# Django 1.10 urls deprecation

Tags: django, django-urls

have some deprecation warning.
Here is the problem:

```
RemovedInDjango110Warning: Support for string view arguments to url()
is deprecated and will be removed in Django 1.10 
(got django.views.static.serve). Pass the callable instead.
'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT,
```

Here is the urls:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^ckeditor/', include('ckeditor_uploader.urls')),
    url(r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve', {
            'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT,
        }),
    url(r'^post/(\d+)$', post),
    url(r'^(\w+)$', category),
    url(r'^$', category),
]
```

How to fix it? Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Replace function paths in string with actual view functions. For instance:

```
from django.views.static import serve
...
url(r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', serve, {
        'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT,
    }),
```